# Deploy zipped EAR to Wildfly via scp

Tags: wildfly

I am (finally) upgrading from JBoss5.1 to Wildfly 9.0.2.Final (standalone).  I am trying to learn how to redeploy a zipped EAR via scp, hoping to have it picked up by the deployment scanner.  Per the documentation, all I have to do is set auto-deploy-zipped="true" in standalone.xml (in the deployment descriptor), then copy the .ear into the deployments folder.  However, when I do so the scanner places a 'failed' file in the deployments folder with this message:

"There is already a deployment called EAR with the same runtime name EAR.ear"

It sounds like it will not automatically redeploy.  I tried adding a signal file named Ear.ear.dodeploy to deployments, but this made no change.

I am able to deploy the EAR via the administration console, but I'm hoping to 'save time' with this scp approach.  Hasn't saved time yet!  :)

Thanks for any help.

Josh

Comment: I just want to point out if you're using maven you could deploy with the [wildfly-maven-plugin](https://docs.jboss.org/wildfly/plugins/maven/latest/) or use a CLI script to deploy it as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured this out.  It turns out that the auto-deploy scheme won't work if you originally deployed the .ear via the administration console.  The fix was simply to remove the .ear via the administration console, then take the steps indicated above.  Now it deploys and redeploys as expected.

Comment: To be clear, there is no need for the trigger file Ear.ear.dodeploy.